# Screen elements partially not tappable

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm experiencing some weird problems on my cordova app on iOS (on Android everything works fine). Sometimes the screen (only on iPhones, not on iPads - here works everything fine too!) seems to be partially covered by an invisible layer - that's the feel you get while working with the app. I can't tap some elements nor can I scroll views.

This is the case where I can reproduce the error (not every time - this error occurs randomly).

At first I take a photo within an issue (#issue-viewer is open) - plugin cordova-plugin-camera will be used. Then I'll tap onto the photo to edit it - #olImageViewer and .image-viewer are created and shown. Maybe it will be possible tap once on an element. Nothing within .image-viewer .content reacts to my taps. If I was able to make a small modification and try to close the window I'll be asked to save those modifications - so another popup appears (last picture). Nearly the same problem here! I'm not able to click the red buttons, but the green one is accessible. BUT: the overlay at the edges of the screen is always tappable!

Short addition: I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.5 as CSS framework. #issue-viewer is based on their modal-class.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After debugging with GapDebug I can clearly say: there is nothing that could prevent elements being tapped. z-indexes are set properly.

Following software versions are in use:

> OS X: 10.11.3
>
> cordova: 6.0.0
>
> cordova iOS platform: 3.9.2
>
> node: 5.6.0
>
> Xcode: 7.2.1

Following plugins are installed:

> com.dvdbrink.cordova.indexeddb 0.1.0 "Cordova-indexedDB"
>
> cordova-plugin-camera 1.2.0 "Camera"
>
> cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.5.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
>
> cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"
>
> cordova-plugin-file-opener2 2.0.2 "File Opener2"
>
> cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.5.0 "File Transfer"
>
> cordova-plugin-google-analytics 0.8.1 "Google Universal Analytics
>   Plugin"
>
> cordova-plugin-googleplayservices 19.0.3 "Google Play Services for
>   Android"
>
> cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.2.0 "InAppBrowser"
>
> cordova-plugin-network-information 1.1.0 "Network Information"
>
> cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.0.0 "Splashscreen"
>
> cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.0.0 "StatusBar"
>
> cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.0 "Whitelist"
>
> phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 4.1.0 "BarcodeScanner"

If you need any additional information feel free to ask for it. :)

Thanks in advance!

/edit: I replaced position: fixed by absolute and updated display: table to flex. Didn't change anything though :/

Answer (score 0):

Same here. It seems to be an issue with the dismissal of the camera on the cordova plugin.